# How can I find my leaked Adobe hint?

Tags: password-recovery

I got the email from Adobe Customer Care informing me that my password was part of a great password leak [reported by XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1286/). So I’m supposed to change my password anywhere that I used that password. Unfortunately, Adobe has unhelpfully reset everyone’s passwords, so I can’t test what my password was or see the hint, to know which password I need to reset. Is there a victims’ help database that allows me to look up my old password hint so that I can figure out which password I used at Adobe?

Comment: I very much doubt it. Adobe probably feels they have enough public password information by now.

Comment: What they're trying to say is that you shouldn't ever be using the same password for more than one login, *especially* if they're storing data like your credit card details. Go and change your passwords in every instance where you've used the same one elsewhere. Use some sort of password management software to help you remember them all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about using a web application.

Comment: That said, this might be helpful: http://blog.lastpass.com/2013/11/take-action-now-check-if-youre-affected.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many services online that will the query the leaked database and tell you your hint an hints by other people using the same password, one of them is provided by Lastpass at https://lastpass.com/adobe/.

Comment: Extremely helpful tool. Thanks for the link.